# Detect mobile, tablet or Desktop on Django

Tags: django, mobile

I need to detect 3 types of device: `tablet`, `mobile` or `desktop`.

I found a script for detecting mobile [on github](https://github.com/macgera/macgera/blob/master/middleware.py), but how I can detect mobile, tablet and desktop?

Answer (score 32):

Based on your prior use of mobile detection middleware, I'd recommend the following:

Pick up the [Python port of MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/?cat=10) ([source code here](https://github.com/ahand/mobileesp/blob/master/Python/mdetect.py)) and drop it into a folder named `mobileesp` in the base of your project (where `manage.py` is). Throw in a blank `__init__.py` file so that Python will see it as a package.

Go ahead and create a new file, `middleware.py`, in that directory, and fill it with:

```
import re
from mobileesp import mdetect

class MobileDetectionMiddleware(object):
    """
    Useful middleware to detect if the user is
    on a mobile device.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        is_mobile = False
        is_tablet = False
        is_phone = False

        user_agent = request.META.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
        http_accept = request.META.get("HTTP_ACCEPT")
        if user_agent and http_accept:
            agent = mdetect.UAgentInfo(userAgent=user_agent, httpAccept=http_accept)
            is_tablet = agent.detectTierTablet()
            is_phone = agent.detectTierIphone()
            is_mobile = is_tablet or is_phone or agent.detectMobileQuick()

        request.is_mobile = is_mobile
        request.is_tablet = is_tablet
        request.is_phone = is_phone
```

Lastly, make sure to include `'mobileesp.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your settings file.

With that in place, in your views (or anywhere that you have a request object) you can check for `is_phone` (for any modern smartphones), `is_tablet` (for modern tablets) or `is_mobile` (for any mobile devices whatsoever).

Comment: can I detect/distinguish with it `ios`, `android`, `windows phone`?

Comment: @andi - Yes, you could use it to distinguish; look at the mdetect python code, there are methods like `detectIphoneOrIpod`, `detectAndroidPhone`, or `detectWindowsPhone` that you could store into boolean variables on the request object. It's well commented, so make sure you are using exactly the detection methods you need.

Comment: Well, @learnJQueryUI, I can only speculate - I answered the question several months after the user (macgera) posted it, so there's a chance he hasn't even looked at it.

Comment: what about [django-user_agents](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents) packages ? it seems more close for the question, take a peek

Comment: @macgera asks how to detect mobile, tablet and DESKTOP. This answer doesn't solve the desktop part or am I missing something?

Comment: @CarlBjörknäs the assumption here is that if `is_mobile` is False (which is to say, it's neither a smartphone or tablet) that it should be treated as a desktop.

Comment: mobileesp last updated 2017. See https://github.com/ahand/mobileesp.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/). It has been recently ported to Python for Django web app framework. It can detect various classes and tiers of devices (including smatphones, tablets).

Answer (score 2):

Use [django-user_agents](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents)

```
from django_user_agents.utils import get_user_agent

def my_view(request):
    user_agent = get_user_agent(request)
    if user_agent.is_mobile:
        # identified as a mobile phone (iPhone, Android phones, Blackberry, Windows Phone devices etc)
    if user_agent.is_tablet:
        # identified as a tablet device (iPad, Kindle Fire, Nexus 7 etc)
    if user_agent.is_pc:
        # identified to be running a traditional "desktop" OS (Windows, OS X, Linux)
```

It uses [`user_agents`](https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents) under the hood.

Comment: Not maintained since 2019, proposed move to Jazzband. See https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents/issues/34.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some quick and simple solution, you can try [handset detection's](http://handsetdetection.com) javascript that enables you create simple redirection rules.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this and I stumbled upon [django-mobile](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile) which does exactly that.

Comment: Last commit in 2016