# How to handle web and mobile requests in django view

Tags: android, python, json, django, rest

I know this is a pretty simple question, but I haven't understood how to tackle this problem.

I have a model called Restaurant with information about a restaurant (name, location, etc). I have a view that handles requests to the url localhost:8000/restaurants and returns a JSON representation of the restaurants using django-rest-framework. I've made it this way because I'm consuming this data from an android app.

Now I want to access the same url from the web, but this time I want to see a fully rendered html with the restaurants' info.

So, my specific question is, how can I know (and consequently responds with a JSON stream or html) whether the request is coming from the android app or from a web browser if both requests are pointed to the same url and view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django Rest Framework's [TemplateHTMLRenderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer). It conditionally outputs either JSON or HTML page based on the type of request. You can define the following attributes for the View that you are using

```
class YourView(generics.TypOfView):
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer,)
    template_name = 'path_to_template.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment yet, so I will post it in the answer.

You might want to try to create the middleware as described by Adam [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119594/detect-mobile-tablet-or-desktop-on-django), and in your views you can perform checking with is_phone, is_tablet and then send response in appropriate format

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But, what if the user accesses the url through the browser of his smartphone? It is going to be detect as is_phone but I still want to show him the html. I only want to return the JSON feed if the request is coming from the native android/iOS app. What do you suggest?